# Connection Neo4j with Glassfish via Rest

Tags: rest, jdbc, glassfish, jersey, neo4j

Hello and thanks for your time!
I have been looking for solution long enough, but didn't find **how to connect glassfish with built-in Jersey via Rest.** Actually, it's not a point make it via Rest, but I found out that I can't do that anyway else, if I plan using not-embedded neo4j.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-java-rest-client-example.html
In the manual I need to install Jersey, but that Jersey is different than Glassfish's one, there's no needed classes inside.
I cant just replace Jersey files in Glassfish because of GF incompability. So, do I need to use another Jersey client, foreing to Glassfish, for Rest queries?

I found also framework neo4j-rest-graphdb, but I'm not sure it will work and probably is what I need. http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-rest-graphdb/2.0.0-M06/

I found JDBC driver for Neo4j - is this a better for these purposes? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j uses jersey version 1.* while glassfish uses version 2.*

The API has been changed as you can check in their respective docs :

- [https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.17/client-api.html](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)
- https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

You basically need to create a client in both cases, and then define a webresource in 1.*, and a webtarget in 2.*

The import paths were also modified.

For instance, the client in 1.* is :

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
```

while in 2.* it is :

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
```

You should [check the API](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/overview-summary.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for such complex answer!

Comment: Actually I had to use Jersey with jetty to call neo4j 2 weeks ago, and I tried the example in the neo4j doc with jersey 2.* which of course didn't work, that's how I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Glassfish 4. You can use the Jersey client APIs bundled with it you don't need to install one. Some of the client class names in the Jersey2 client are different then Jersey 1